# Silex: jQuery AJAX request throws exception - No route found for "GET ..."

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, silex

I'm trying to make an ajax call on tr click like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/segments/ajaxGetHostsSegment",
    data: {
        deelgebied: deelgebiedid
    },
    success: function( data ) {
        // CHECK ID'S WITH ID'S IN FORM AND CHECK CHECKBOXES
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(thrownError);
    }
})
```

In my routes file I have:

```
$app->get('/segments/ajaxgethostssegment', 'Segments\Controller\IndexController::ajaxGetHostsSegment')->bind('segments.gethosts');
```

My Controller action:

```
public function ajaxGetHostsSegment(Application $app, Request $request)
{
    $deelgebied = $request->request->get('data');
    var_dump($deelgebied);
    die();
}
```

But I always get the error:

```
No route found for "GET /segments/ajaxGetHostsSegment" (from "http://mext-pst.localhost:8080/segments/view/PSS1400023")
```

Comment: Why did you just remove the `$app->post()` part ... and added `type: "GET"` to your question? Now my answer isn't suited anymore. That's pretty disappointing ... Stop doing these kinds of edits or nobody will help you anymore. You should've opened a new question. You're now having a completely different problem.

Comment: I need to get data from the database, I don't need to post something to the database.

Comment: Yes but the original problem was that you created a GET request and defined only a POST route... That's a totally different thing now. Sorry i don't have time for this. Open a new question next time and don't edit the original code (append a new version maybe) unless you've made a mistake when pasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wrong http request method:**

You're sending a *GET* request instead of a *POST* request with jQuery.

`$.ajax()` performs a *GET* request by default.

Silex throws the exception because you have not defined a route for *GET* but only for *POST*.

```
$app->post('..')
```

**solution: add the request-type to `$.ajax`**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    // ...
});
```