# How to use Ajax queries with Silex?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, silex

In order to build my new site, I decided to try the Silex framework. I read a lot in the doc so I had no problems until now.

I'm making a voting system and I'd like to use it dynamically with Ajax.

So, first I declared the route :

**routes.php**

```
$app->match('/ajax/vote', mysite\Controller\HomeController::voteAction');
```

I registered the service :

**app.php**

```
$app['dao.ajax'] = $app->share(function ($app) {
    return new mysite\DAO\AjaxDAO($app['db']);
});
```

Then, there is the associated controller :

**HomeController.php**

```
public function voteAction(Application $app, Request $request) {        

    $vote = new Vote();
    $vote->setVoteId($request->get('vote_id'));
    $vote->setBookId($request->get('book_id'));
    $vote->setVoterIp($request->get('IP'));

    $voteAction = $app['dao.ajax']->saveVote($vote);
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig');
}
```

So when I click on the Vote button, it is supposed to (re)render the index page.

My DAO class :

**DAO.php**

```
namespace mysite\DAO;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

abstract class DAO 
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct(Connection $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    protected function getDb() {
        return $this->db;
    }

    protected abstract function buildDomainObject($row);
}
```

Then, the voting function :

**AjaxDAO.php**

```
namespace mysite\DAO;

use mysite\Domain\Vote;

class AjaxDAO extends DAO 
{
    protected function buildDomainObject($row) {
        $vote = new Vote();
        $vote->setVoteId($row['vote_id']);
        $vote->setBookId($row['book_id']);
        $vote->setVoterIp($row['vt_ip']);
        return $vote;
    }

    public function saveVote(Vote $vote) {

        $voteData = array(
            'vote_id' => $vote->getVoteId(),
            'book_id' => $vote->getBookId(),
            'vt_ip' => $vote->getVoterIp()
        );
        $this->getDb()->insert('t_vote', $voteData);
    }
}
```

The Vote class :

**Vote.php**

```
namespace mysite\Domain;

class Vote
{
    private $id;

    private $vote_id;

    private $book_id;

    private $vt_ip;


    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getVoteId() {
        return $this->vote_id;
    }

    public function setVoteId($vote_id) {
        $this->vote_id = $vote_id;
    }

    public function getBookId() {
        return $this->book_id;
    }

    public function setBookId($book_id) {
        $this->book_id = $book_id;
    }

    public function getVoterIp() {
        return $this->vt_ip;
    }

    public function setVoterIp($vt_ip) {
        $this->vt_ip = $vt_ip;
    }
}
```

Now, the jQuery with the Ajax in it :

**vote.js**

```
$('button').on('click', function like(e) {
    $(this).off('click');
    e.preventDefault();

    var vote_id = '{{ vote_id }}';
    var book_id = $(this).attr('data-book');
    var IP = '{{ getUserIp() }}';

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/vote',
            data: {'POST_type': 'vote', 'book_id': book_id, 'IP': IP},
            success: function(html) {
                $('button').removeClass('active').addClass('disabled');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    };
});
```

As you may have understand, when I click the button VOTE, I have an error alert. When I visit the link *mysite/ajax/vote*, I have this error :

```
Notice: Undefined property: mysite\DAO\AjaxDAO::$request
```

I checked in the Official Documentation and in previous StackOverflow questions but I found only the [question 22011254](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011254/silex-jquery-ajax-request-throws-exception-no-route-found-for-get) and it didn't help me...

**EDIT :** I just read that Silex supports only Json data exchange with Ajax. Maybe is this the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error in `AjaxDAO.php` method `saveVote`. You try to use property `$this->request` that is not defined in this class. Better set vote fields in controller and that transmit it to `saveVote`.

**HomeController.php**

```
public function voteAction(Application $app, Request $request) {
    ...

    $vote = new Vote();
    $vote->setVoteId($request->get('vote_id'));
    $vote->setBookId($request->get('book_id'));
    $vote->setVoterIp($request->get('vt_ip'));

    $voteAction = $app['dao.ajax']->saveVote($vote);

    ...
}
```

**AjaxDAO.php**

```
public function saveVote(Vote $vote) {
    $voteData = array(
        'vote_id' => $vote->getVoteId(),
        ...
    );
    $this->getDb()->insert('t_vote', $voteData);
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for your answer but now, my error is : `Notice: Undefined property: mysite\Controller\HomeController::$request`

Comment: `$request`, not `$this->request`, I've changed my answer

Comment: I edited my code with your answer and I still have an error :  `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO t_vote (musite\Domain\Voteid, mysite\Domain\Votevote_id, mysite\Domain\Votebook_id, mysite\Domain\Votevt_ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null, null]: `

... And I used `(array)` in AjaxDAO because when I wanted to insert $data it was expecting an array and it was an object.

Comment: oh, you don't use orm... than create array with all fields and values that should be placed id DB, look in answer

Comment: I edited my code thanks to your new answer and I have this error `An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO t_vote (vote_id, book_id, vt_ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, null]:` So I thought that the error was because I accessed directly mysite/ajax/vote but when I went to the index and clicked the button, it returns me an Error 500.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth checking what is in the headers sent with your ajax request. In silex `application/json` requests are not handled as standard `x-form`. You can remedy this using a solution mentioned in [silex cookbook](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/cookbook/json_request_body.html) (this valid for both 2.* and 1.3.*).

As for the notice I'd start looking here:

```
$vote->setVoteId($request->get('vote_id'));
$vote->setBookId($request->get('book_id'));
$vote->setVoterIp($request->get('IP'));
```

If you're making some non-standard post request maybe those `$request->get` method calls return something other than you expect (e.g. request object?). Since you have no validation or sanitisation going on you might have not noticed.

You can also change this:

```
$app->match('/ajax/vote', mysite\Controller\HomeController::voteAction');
```

to:

```
$app->post('/ajax/vote', mysite\Controller\HomeController::voteAction');
```

since `match` without specified methods will match every type of request. Might not matter now, but will save you trouble later.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Silex and i am not that familiar with it but viewing [documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/usage.html#other-methods).

> *You can create controllers for most HTTP methods. Just call one of these methods on your application: get, post, put, delete, patch.*

In your HomeController.php you use get(), shouldn't this HTTP method be used in ajax as well?

**Example**

```
$('button').on('click', function like(e) {
    $(this).off('click');
    e.preventDefault();

    var vote_id = 'Vote ID';
    var book_id = $(this).attr('data-book');
    var IP = getUserIp();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/ajax/vote?vote_id='+vote_id+'&book_id='+book_id+'vt_ip='+IP,
            success: function(html) {
                $('button').removeClass('active').addClass('disabled');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    };
});
```